# Unmanaged Switches Effect on RSTP Ring?

Tags: spanning-tree, switching

What will happen if, `SW1`, `SW2`, `SW3` are managed RSTP ring switches. And I add unmanaged `SW4` and `SW5`  the ring (both `SW4` and `SW5` are connected together) like this:

[image: digram]

This project is currently at early stage. We are just trying to figure out if the hardware-specific client demand is feasible. Going with the unmanaged switches solution would reduce costs significantly.

Sel-2730M configurations will use BPDU Guard.
The "unmanaged" portion (blue portion in the diagram) of the network wont have any loops.

Comment: Please clarify your question. The diagram you posted is not clear. Also it depends on the switch hardware used so please go into detail which switches you are using.

Comment: Thanks for adding a more detailed diagram.  This leads to a few other questions, such as, what is the configuration on the SEL-2730M switches?  For example, are you utilizing BPDUGuard?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the unmanaged switches do not support RSTP, they should forward the BPDUs as any other L2 multicast and simply flood them out the VLAN. If they do, things will work fine since the managed switches will receive the BPDUs. The unmanagad switches would basically be transparent to the managed switches from a STP perspective.

Worst case the switches would consume the BPDUs but not act on them and create a bridging loop. I've never seen this myself but heard of such stories from others.

Comment: One more possible worst case scenario: if somebody loops a couple ports on the unmanaged switch

Comment: regardless of whether the rstp switches block, you get broadcast radiation from the unmanaged loop... that was my point in saying this.  The question says nothing about bpdu guard so we can only speculate about the configs

Comment: @MikePennington According to the data sheet on the [SEL-2730M](https://www.selinc.com/SEL-2730M/) switches that are listed in the diagram, they do support BPDUGuard. If that is in use, it mitigates the switch loop issue somewhat. Devices on the unmanaged switches may lose access, but they won't take down the rest of the network. But that depends on the configuration of the SEL switches, which we don't have.

Comment: @MikePennington True, I have asked for clarification on the original question so as not to be speculating.